# Creating a secure mySQL database connection with WebMatrix in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, webmatrix

I've created a connection script to my database in WebMatrix with php by learning from a book, and it states I should place the connection script outside the web directory so people can't access it in the browser. But if I do that I don't know how I'm supposed to retrieve it since every import/include starts at the web directory.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this please? Thank you.

My connection script:

```
 <?php
 # Selects the database

 DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'secret');
 DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret');
 DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'secret');

 $dbc_accounts = @mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR die ('Could not       connect to MySQL');

 @mysql_select_db (DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not select the database');

 // Function for escaping data
 function escape_data ($data) 
 {
     global $dbc_accounts;
     if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) 
     {
         $data = stripslashes($data);
     }
     return mysql_real_escape_string(trim($data), $dbc_accounts);
 }
```

using it:

```
 require_once ('mysql_connect.php');
```

Comment: You should be able to include files from outside of the web directory. You could use an absolute path...what have you tried so far?

Comment: Absolute Path....thanks I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once ('../some/place/secure/mysql_connect.php');
```